# Regular expression for allowing a user to enter alphanumeric characters and only one non-alphanumeric character

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am using `Asp.Net/C#` .I am using `RegularExpressionValidator` control for validating my password `textbox`.My passowrd field can allow alphanumeric characters and only one non-alphanumeric character.Can anybody how do I allow user to enter such a pattern.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that? (Add anchors if necessary - not sure about how the validators apply the regex)

```
\w*(\W\w*)?
```

Comment: Can you explain the pattern please

Comment: \w is alphanumeric ("word"-characters), \W is non-alphanumeric. So the pattern is: any number of \w, optionally followed by a single \W and any number of \w